# Does std::list's end() iterator position change when erasing?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, erase

In the following loop I'm using a pre-calculated end iterator:

```
std::list::iterator end = MyList.end();

for (std::list::iterator it = MyList.begin(); it != end ;) 
    it = MyList.erase(it);
```

When erasing an element in a std::list, can the MyList.end() change its value so that `end != MyList.end()` anymore?

Comment: Rather than try to edit the accepted answer to be more comprehensive, I edited the question so it's just about `std::list`.  One should read each container's documentation for the specifics of what invalidation guarantees it does or does not offer.

Comment: In general, don't save `end()` , it only works for some containers, so don't get into the habit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

n3376 23.3.5.4

> ```
> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> ```
>
> Effects: Invalidates only the iterators and references **to the erased elements.**

Comment: Just for completeness, keep in mind that this applies to `std::list` and some other container types but isn't true for all container types (such as `std::vector`).

Comment: @ForEveR search set/map erase :)